# How can I make a custom fill handle pattern?

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula, countif, excel-2011

I have a column `A3:A71` I wish to populate with values

```
=COUNTIF(B3:B71,B3)
```

Where the second argument is incremented with every cell.
Obviously I don't want to copy this function every time, so I was hoping that fill handle would help me. However although it correctly increments the second argument of `COUNTIF`, it also increments the first one. Even if I correctly populate the first two or three cells in the column `A3:A71` with the values

```
=COUNTIF(B3:B71,B3)
=COUNTIF(B3:B71,B4)
=COUNTIF(B3:B71,B5)
```

when I drag down from the bottom right corner, I get the function:

```
=COUNTIF(B6:B74,B6)
=COUNTIF(B6:B74,B7)
=COUNTIF(B6:B74,B8)

=COUNTIF(B9:B77,B9)
=COUNTIF(B9:B77,B10)
=COUNTIF(B9:B77,B11)
```

Can anybody please tell me how can I force the first argument to stay the same while the second one is increased correctly?

I am using MS Office 2011 for MacOS, but a Windows solution would be just as helpful.

Comment: No. But it seems to work. What is the dollar sign supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
 =COUNTIF(B$3:B$71,B3)
```

There are further details at [OwenBloggers.com](http://www.owenbloggers.com/2011/05/13/excel-tip-of-the-week-absolute-and-relative-cell-references/) including a table:

[image: SO28445161 example]

and mention that other terms are “absolute cell reference” and “locking”.